# GCM stopped working after uploading to play store

Tags: android

I created an application which uses Google could messaging and it is working perfectly fine.
Then,
I Export the signed application with a new keystore.
Upload it to playstore
Link the sender ID on the publishing page.
I uninstall the unsigned app and install the new app from play store but now I am unable to receive the messages. The server console show message sent successfuly along with the messageID but there is no notification on the device.

Comment: If you update apk GCM messages can ignore your old version

Comment: i saw that new device ids were generated with the apk installation from play and i have used them on the server side also. Is there anything like production/sandbox key ? or the keystore to be updated somewhere ?

Comment: When an application is updated, it should invalidate its existing registration ID, as it is not guaranteed to work with the new version. Because there is no lifecycle method called when the application is updated, the best way to achieve this validation is by storing the current application version when a registration ID is stored.http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html

Comment: Yes, I have taken care of that. I have removed my device's id from the database and inserted the new id.I increased the number of retries also to be on the safer side.but all this isnt helping

Comment: i also tried uninstalling the app from play store and installing the signed apk directly and that works fine. There is definitely some configuration on the API console or the Play store console that I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Check your **manifest** file. If you can use **GCM** without the

```
android:protectionLevel=signature
```

you're probably using an incorrect package name in the permission object. Check if you did change the package name to your app package name.

**So instead of:**

```
<permission android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

**Use:**

```
<permission android:name="YOUR.PACKAGENAME.HERE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="YOUR.PACKAGENAME.HERE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, 
removing the android:protectionLevel=signature tag fixed the issue. I understand that this means now other apps can also fetch the notifications that i send.